# Android ringer mode changing . Based on Accelerometer values

Tags: android

I want to make an android app which will change the ringer mode to silent, normal, or vibrate based on accelerometer values.  how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't easily answered. You should read some documentation about the sensors.

- [Sensor Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)

To change the ringer mode, you can use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and do something like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL); // AudioManager.WHATEVER_YOU_WANT
```